# Getting smaller size for text input field in django bootstrap

Tags: html, css, django, twitter-bootstrap

I am using textfields, radiobuttons, textarea etc in my form. The textfield size is very small and looks very bad:

[image]

How can I make slightly larger? How the height of text area is smaller than that of gender field?

Code is:

```
<div class='form-group'>
                    <label class='control-label col-md-2 col-md-offset-2' for='id_name'>Name</label>
                    <div class='col-md-6'>

                        {% render_field form.name class="form-control" placeholder="Full Name" type="text" %}

                        {% if form.name.errors %}
                        <div class="alert alert-danger tpad">
                            {{ form.name.errors.as_text }}
                        </div>

                        {% endif %}


                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- name ends here -->
                {# Gender goes here #}
                <div class='form-group'>

                <label class='control-label col-md-2 col-md-offset-2' for='id_name'>Gender</label>
                    <div class='col-md-6'>

                        {% for radio in form.gender %}
                        {{ radio }}
                        {% endfor %}    
                        {{form.gender.errors}}


                    </div>
                </div>



                <!-- enroll ment number -->
                <div class='form-group'>
                    <label class='control-label col-md-2 col-md-offset-2' for='id_enrollment_number'>Enrollment Number</label>
                    <div class='col-md-6'>


                        {% render_field form.enrollment_no class='form-control' placeholder='Enrollment Number' type='text' %}
                        {% if form.enrollment_no.errors %}
                        <div class="alert alert-danger tpad">
                            {{ form.enrollment_no.errors.as_text }}
                        </div>

                        {% endif %}

                    </div>
                </div>





                <div class='form-group'>
                    <label class='control-label col-md-2 col-md-offset-2' for='id_faculty_name'>Faculty Name</label>
                    <div class='col-md-6'>

                        {% render_field form.faculty_name   class='form-control' rows="1" cols="1" placeholder='Faculty Name' type='text' %}
                        {% if form.faculty_name.errors %}
                        <div class="alert alert-danger tpad">
                            {{ form.faculty_name.errors.as_text }}
                        </div>

                        {% endif %}
                    </div>
                </div>
```

The code generated is:

```
<div class='form-group'>
                    <label class='control-label col-md-2 col-md-offset-2' for='id_name'>Name</label>
                    <div class='col-md-6'>

                        <input class="form-control" id="id_name" maxlength="200" name="name" placeholder="Full Name" type="text" />




                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- name ends here -->

                <div class='form-group'>

                <label class='control-label col-md-2 col-md-offset-2' for='id_name'>Gender</label>
                    <div class='col-md-6'>


                        <select id="id_gender" name="gender">
<option value="Male">Male</option>
<option value="Female">Female</option>
</select>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Solution: The text size rendered by bootstrap was 20px. I changed it manually to 40px, here:

```
.uneditable-input{display:inline-block;height:40px;padding:4px 6px;margin-bottom:10px;font-size:14px;line-height:20px;color:#555;vertical-align:middle;-webkit-border-radius:4px;-moz-border-radius:4px;border-radius:4px}input,textarea,
```

Comment: Which library is responsible for providing `render_field` tempalte tag? Could you also add the HTML for the field which is finally generated?

Comment: @AKS Sorry for being late. Have a look on my edits.

Answer (score 1):

Since your code generate an id for the name input, adding (or update) this rule in your CSS would do the trick

```
#id_name {
  height: 30px;       /*  where you give it same height as your select  */
}
```

Another way, more generic for your form elements (input text and select), could be like this

```
form-control select,
form-control input[type=text] {
  height: 30px;
}
```

Comment: @learner You add the class `form-control` to your input text but not your select, which could be why they differ, but since I don't have access to your CSS or HTML, I can't be sure

Comment: It is not working. After removing the class form-control, nothing happens.

Comment: @learner Add `form-control` to your select too and see what happens,... and if nothing, use one of the classes I suggested in my answer, and if you use the latter, you need to add the `form-control` class to your select

Comment: thank you for the help. The text size rendered by bootstrap was 20px. I changed it manually to 40px, here: .uneditable-input{display:inline-block;height:40px;padding:4px 6px;margin-bottom:10px;font-size:14px;line-height:20px;color:#555;vertical-align:middle;-webkit-border-radius:4px;-moz-border-radius:4px;border-radius:4px}input,textarea, Its working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should resize the box like: cols or you should make it as a textarea.

For example that part of the box:

```
{% render_field form.name class="form-control"   cols="1" placeholder="Full Name" type="text" %}
```

Comment: The `rows` attribute is only valid for `textarea`s, not `input`s.

Comment: Ок so @learner can make it as a textarea or just change the cols